# Java: OutputStream and InputStream

Tags: java

I have a class CBZip2OutputStream from "apache bzi2 library" , it can transform binary data stream to bzi2 data stream.
But I need to archive a string.
Therefore, i think, i should create an input stream from that outputstream, write that data to outputstream and read archived data from inputstream... but how to link outputstream and inputstream?

Answer (score 2):

You can just read from input stream and write to output stream. It is a common practice. IOUtils.copy() (from jakarta commons) does it, so you event do not need to implement the loop.

Alternatively you can use PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably want a DataOutputStream: it is designed to take primitives and objects and convert them to bytes. It does handle strings as well.

Next, use piped I/O: PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream. You can use them to link streams together, similar to piping input from one process into another from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several method to get an InputStream out of an OutputStream.

- write the data the data into a memory buffer (ByteArrayOutputStream) get the byteArray and read it again with a ByteArrayInputStream. This is the best approach if you're sure your data fits into memory.
- copy your data to a temporary file and read it back.
- use pipes: this is the best approach both for memory usage and speed (you can take full advantage of the multi-core processors) and also the standard solution offered by Oracle.
- use "circular buffers" or pipes trough an external library.

Here is a [complete tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/io-tools/wiki/ConvertOutputStreamInputStream).